# Video Streaming in HTML5

Tags: html, video-streaming

How does one go about streaming video in HTML5 ? I can go with using a single browser of the latest version if I have to.
I need to be able to start playing from any location of the movie even if the entire video has not been loaded by the browser.
[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) ?
I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263977/html5-video-streaming) and no one has answered.

> Does not allow the viewer to skip to the middle of a video in any
>   browser. They must watch the video straight through start to finish,
>   which is not ideal.

This is the main point for streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently if you want to use pure HTML5 and work cross-browser you are limited to progressive streaming with the <video> element.

While that still does allow the user to skip ahead via the scrubber or programatically by setting the .currentTime there will still be some buffering while the browser re-loads enough content to be comfortable playing smoothly.

Solutions like Smooth Streaming, HLS do not work across browsers today so you would require a Flash or Silverlight plugin, though with MPEG-DASH being recognized by the W3C there is some hope for the future as samples like this demonstrate http://dash-mse-test.appspot.com/release-notes.html

For today however if you want to stick with an HTML5 solution and you have source in a format the works with the browser then you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has implemented the Media Source API in the mean time. Hoping the rest will follow.
http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/

#### Abstract

This specification extends HTMLMediaElement to allow JavaScript to generate media streams for playback. Allowing JavaScript to generate streams facilitates a variety of use cases like adaptive streaming and time shifting live streams.